# Google+ API to get insights data of Google+ pages

Tags: google-api, google-plus

For a project, I need to get following information from a Google+ brand page

1. count reviews
2. get rating
3. get reviews
4. get reviews time stamps
5. contact information

I have tried finding some API on developers.google.com but failed to get such API. Is there any other way around to get this data? It sounds like a dumb question, but unfortunately I stuck and getting no help from anywhere, that's why I am writing here.

Thanks

Saurabh

Answer (score -1):

You can download a bunch of libraries here that make using these api's pretty simple.
https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/

Look around the pages they also have plenty of example.
https://developers.google.com/+/web/ 
https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/javascript